# RaspberryPi turn off problem

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

I have been working on raspberry pi, connected to mains power using adapter. But in my area electricity goes again again, so as electricity goes down, inverter in my home takes microseconds to up due to which raspberry pi get shutdown and got re-started. This is mainly due to the microseconds inverter taking to up.

SO I want to avoid these unwanted shutdown. Is there any cheap solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: a large cap might be enough, maybe 10,000uf, or a super cap, but then you have to be careful feeding it...

Comment: where should I exactly connect that ? Is that work if I connect at 5V and GND GPIO? I am using pi 4 and powering it using Type-C.

Comment: yes, 5v and GND. those might have continuity to the USB out socket, which might be able to handle more current than a breadboard pin. You might also be able to use some USB chargers to power the pi and get recharged at the same time, but most battery packs won't let you use and charge at same time, but some do...